# Is it Thread Safe to read from lower index elements of an struct array while it is being filled with data in main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer, stdatomic

**Original Question:**

I got an array of structs and filling it in a separate thread while reading it in main thread:

```
struct DataModel MyData[1024];

struct DataModel
{
    bool IsFilled;
    float a;
    float b;
}
```

- I have a Thread which is filling the `Mydata` array from 0 index to the last index(in above it is 1024).
- Then i get the last filled struct index out from the filling thread.
- And then i try to read the the values of the element with one index lower than the filled one.
- Let 's assume that when the 500th element is filled i read the value from 499 element of `MyData` array, so i assure that i am not reading the array element which is being written.

**Q1:** Is this thread safe?

**Q2:** is there chance of occurring undefined behavior or misreading the vales?

---

**Further Edits:**

The question was improperly edited to add more details and that's why it introduced inconsistency over answers so i separated the previous edits to improve consistency over answers and accepted answer.

**Edit 1**:
this is a suggestion of the possible implementation. though it may show false results, but just i wanted to ask about thread-safety and and undefined behavior, the following solution may show various result but i was trying to ask about thread safety first.

```
std::atomic<int> FilledIndex;
    void FillingMyData(struct DataModel myData[])
    {
      for(size_t i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
      {
        myData[i].a = rand();
        myData[i].b = rand();
        myData[i].IsFilled = true;

    FilledIndex = i;
  }
}

int main()
{
     std::thread ReadThread(FillingMyData, MyData);
     while(FilledIndex < 1024)
     {
          std::cout << MyData[FilledIndex].a;
     }
     ReadThread.join();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Then i get the last filled struct index out from the filling thread."_ What does it mean?

Comment: Recommendation: Learn how to use clang's thread-sanitizer. It'll give you a definitive answer if you're in doubt.

Comment: my development environment is vscode as IDE and nuwen MinGW64 build for compiling on windows, is it possible to use clang `thread-sanitizer` working in this environment?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist It does not give you definitive answers. Just that it doesn't find anything does not mean that there is no threading issue.

Comment: @yekanchi I don't know. Sorry. I don't code on Windows that much.

Comment: What is the initial value of `FilledIndex`?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Please elaborate. Are you saying that there may be data races that thread-sanitizer may not detect? Please provide examples.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Aside from [this](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerAlgorithm) mentioning that it can miss data races (and that's only one of several ways), there's also other kinds of race conditions that are not data races. Just that your accesses are synchronized does not mean that they are happening in the order that you actually want.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist [Here](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk/test/tsan/thread_leak3.c?view=markup) is another one. The commit message tells us that this simple test is flaky when you add a sleep instead of the barrier (sort of ironic). Also, why would I use _"[settings with 3x (less accurate analysis) and 9x (more accurate analysis) overhead](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html)"_ if it already detected all races anyway? Don't get me wrong, it pays to be able to wield a thread sanitizer, but a clean run is not proof of thread safety.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist It's essentially obvious that any tool cannot detect all data races.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of your code: what are you trying to do and how do you attempt to do it? What's the purpose of `while(FilledIndex < 1024)`?

Comment: **Significantly editing a question, with different source code, after answers have been posted, without a very big warning that changes are significant, is a big no no**!

Comment: @yekanchi Please ask a new question if you want to ask about different code.

Comment: `bool IsFilled;` is just a waste of 4 bytes (including padding for alignment) because you fill in order.  Without being `atomic<>`, it's completely useless because you can't read it unless you already know that no other thread can be writing it.  But you don't really want to make it atomic, that can defeat auto-vectorization once the whole array is written.  The atomic FilledIndex is not wonderful, especially with a seq_cst store to it inside the loop (much slower than a `memory_order_release` store).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to work on separate objects in the same array.  Even though an array is an object, it is the elements of the array that we are working on and those are separate objects.  As long as you don't read an element the writer is writing to, then there is no data race and the code has defined behavior.  You do have synchronization issues with your posted code but the other answers here cover hat those are.

What can happen here though is what is called [false sharing](https://web.archive.org/web/20200302130554/https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads).  What happens in these cases is the separate objects are in the same cache line in memory.  When on core/thread changes one object, that cache line gets marked as changed.  This means the other core/thread has to re-sync that line to pull in any changes which means both cores/threads can't run at the same time.  This is a performance penalty only though, and program will still give the correct results, it will just be slower.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux By default it is.  If you use it with a different memory model then  it depends.  Since the user says the writing thread is giving the reading thread the index, I felt it wasn't pertinent to the question/answer.

Comment: Good point, the `std::atomic` part of the code could be removed and the rest would still stand on it's own.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i think `std::Atomic` is necessary for `FilledIndex` but i was using it mistakenly for `IsFilled`

Comment: @yekanchi Well, a `std::atomic<bool>` isn't required for the solution described in the question. And for communicating the indices ready to be read, there are many possible solutions, `std::atomic<std::size_t>` being one of them but not the only one.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the update.  I've updated the answer to talk about the general case and call out they should see the other answers about their specific code.

Answer (score 4):

The code has a data race and will continue to loop forever.

The data race happens because the initial value of `FilledIndex` is `0` so, the first time through the loop, you are reading from the same index to which you are writing (because `i == 0`).

The loop will never end because `i` will *never* reach the terminating value - the loop will exit before setting `FilledIndex` to `1024`.

Comment: You're correct about it running forever, but there is no data race on the first iteration because `FilledIndex` is atomic. Yes, it is a race condition on _every_ iteration (the program's output depends heavily on scheduling), but not a data race.

Comment: @MaxLanghof During the first iteration for *both* threads `FilledIndex == 0` and `i == 0`. Which means *both* loops will execute at the same time on the same index of the array. Then the work thread will explicitly set `FilledIndex = 0` and start working on the `i == 1` iteration of its loop while the output thread *continues* outputting `FilledIndex == 0` data. So until the work thread starts its *second iteration* both threads are accessing the same data in a race condition.

Comment: Only one iteration with a **data** race and also a race **condition** on every iteration! "_the loop will exit before setting FilledIndex to 1024._" hopefully, that would be yet another bug

Answer (score 3):

The code as written is not necessarily safe, and may not do anything useful.

- the initial value of FilledIndex is zero, so it can read data from index zero before writing, including possibly partially written values. You probably want to set it to -1 and wait for it to be >= 0 before output.
- there is nothing to stop the main thread executing indefinitely, outputting the same value at zero forever - it's up to the scheduler; there also is nothing to stop the main thread outputting the value at a given index more than once. You probably want to count from zero to filled index rather than outputting the value at the filled index.

The above concerns may mean that you choose a different means to communicate the value of filled index back to the main thread.

Comment: These are issues with the code but it still has other issues. "_there also is nothing to stop the main thread outputting the value at a given index more than once_" OTOH nothing guarantees that any element in particular is printed at all, as the counter may have advanced beside it!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this code is definitely not thread-safe.

First of all the variable `FilledIndex` is not initialized: as stated by [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/atomic/) if you don't submit any value to the constructor, the atomic variable is left in an uninitialized state.
This can lead to unexpected behaviors.

Another problem is with the exit condition in the main thread, because the for statement in `ReadThread` loops until 1023, so `FilledIndex` will never assume the value 1024 and the main thread never exits.

But the main problem is the unpredictability of the scheduling of your threads: what assures that the `ReadThread` is executed after the main one? Nothing!

So you cannot be sure that you're looping on all values of the array. In fact, if you try to execute many times your program, you'll see that the output every time is different and different values of the array are printed out.

For example, if we name `ReadThread` as **T**, the main thread as **M** and the array as **A**, these are possible schedulings (assuming **A** of size 5 for semplicity):

- T T T M T the output will be A[2]
- M M T M T the output will be A[0] A[0] A[1]

In fact, you're printing A[`FilledIndex`] and you cannot predict how `FilledIndex` will be updated, because it depends from thread scheduling.

I hope that you'll understand what I'm trying to say. For any questions or clarifications, obviously I'm here! I'll reply as soon as possible!

Comment: "_so FilledIndex will never assume the value 1024_" OTOH it's a requirement of the consuming thread that it shouldn't ever reach 1024, so fixing that bug in the producer would introduce another one in  the consumer. Ouch!

Comment: If the reader thread is a "progress bar", it's fine to just print whatever the most recent thing was.  There are possible use-cases for this.  Otherwise yeah, you'd more likely want to read through the array one at a time, and only check that you hadn't reached FilledIndex yet.  (And if so, spin-wait, yield, or sleep, until it increases.)

Comment: @PeterCordes this is true, but from the question I didn't understand that this is the case. What I understand is: I have an array, a producer thread which fills it, and a consumer thread which reads it. The reported code reads different values of the array in different orders every time you execute it, so with your assumption this may (or not may - I haven't time to test it now) be correct. I think that he wants to read all the array...

Comment: I think (hope) the reader is just a trivial example as part of a MCVE.  Different orders, though?  The order is always monotonic, it's just which elements are skipped/not-skipped that's not deterministic.  You can never get a high element printed before a low element.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are right! It's surely monotonic, I just expressed myself incorrectly! I was thinking this but I wrote another thing! Thank you for your clarification.